# sem_post() fail with valid semaphore

Tags: linux, semaphore

I have a queue with a semaphore. At certain point all the calls to `sem_post()` always return 'Invalid argument' error although the semaphore itself is valid

The semaphore is a private member of C++ object which is never deleted, it also can be inspected in gdb. I added `sem_getvalue()` just before the `sem_post()` - the value reads OK and then it fails on `sem_post()`. What could be wrong?

```
CThreadQueue::CThreadQueue(int MaxSize) :
    _MaxSize(MaxSize)
{
    sem_init(&_TaskCount, 0, 0)

    pthread_mutex_init(&_Mutex, 0);
    pthread_create(&_Thread, NULL, CThreadQueue::StartThread, this);
}


CThreadQueue::~CThreadQueue()
{
    pthread_kill(_Thread, SIGKILL);
    sem_destroy(&_TaskCount);
}


int CThreadQueue::AddTask(CThreadTask Task)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_Mutex);
    _Queue.push_back(TempTask);
    sem_post(&_TaskCount)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_Mutex);

    return 0;
}

void *CThreadQueue::StartThread(void *Obj)
{
    ((CThreadQueue*)Obj)->RunThread();
    return NULL;
}

//runs in a separate thread
void CThreadQueue::RunThread()
{
    CThreadQueue::CTask Task;

    while(1) {
        sem_wait(&_TaskCount);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&_Mutex);

        Task = _Queue.front();
        _Queue.pop_front();

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_Mutex);

        if (Task.Callee != NULL)
            Task.Callee->CallBackFunc(NULL, Task.CallParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you produce a test program that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Jack, did you find out what was happening? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, David. I cannot reproduce the problem. It was a long time ago and from the diff I mad the only thing I added was checking sem_wait()

Comment: like this: int SemResult = sem_wait(&_TaskCount);
if (SemResult != 0) {
    if (errno != EINTR) //EINTR is OK: it may be caused by gdb
        LOG_ERRNO << "sem_wait() failed";
    continue; //keep on sem_wating
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be wrong?  Any number of things.  Something else could be destroying the semaphore or overwriting the memory used to store it or the pointer to it.  Another possibility is that you're calling sem_post() too many times and the counter overflows.  A code sample would help.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem and I don't know what could be happening. I've checked that the counter doesn't overflow and the memory is correct, but what is more strange is that sem_post returns -1 but the counter inside is correctly increased...

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, and after a long time figuring out what could be happening, we discovered that the problem occurred because the semaphore was defined inside a struct that had its byte alignment changed to 1 (in this case using the pragma pack(1) directive).

The POSIX semaphores implementation on Linux uses the futex syscall. According to the futex man page, EINVAL is returned when "An operation was not defined or error in page alignment."

In our case, either removing the pragma pack(1) directive or defining the semaphore as the first element of the struct, solved the problem.

Comment: +1 for a great example of why packed structures **should never be used**.